# How save images in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save images in a mysql database. I read one option:

```
INSERT INTO tblname(ID,IMAGE) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('C:/path.jpg'));
```

This option save a null value in the field, when realise select rows of the table, the result is a null value and also don't work in a sql php query.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you get an error? Please add your PHP code so we can see what happens. I would store the path, not an image.

Comment: Note that unless the images are under 100k, it's generally a bad idea to store them in the data base. The file server is usually much better at handling large, blobby, files.

Comment: What is the other option to located a images without static form, i want to store in a database many products with his name,image,price and with a sql query load it in a html page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can save as LONGBLOB datatype in mysql, to store it binary in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE pictures (
    'id' INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'image' LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
)
```

then

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pictures(image)               
        VALUES('".file_get_contents($tmp_image)."')";
```